# Table colgroup col style inconsistency with colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table, col, colgroup

I am trying to highlight a column with cells that use the span attribute, like a overarching header cell.

I tried it in the most obvious way by using the `colgroup` and `col` tag. Unfortunately, this delivers inconsistent results. An overarching cell is highlighted with the first column that spans it but not with consecutive ones (see the example below).

I can see that when using background color on different cols then the overarching cell, if highlighted, would have to have both colors which is not possible. Hence, I think the most consistent result would be that it gets no color. Maybe there some attribute or so I can set to get consistent highlighting?

Test: https://jsfiddle.net/m13d2arf/1/

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="highlight">
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col class="highlight">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can override the background color on the th element.

```
th {
  background-color: white;
}
```

---

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
th {
  background-color: white;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="highlight">
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col class="highlight">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```